# MoQ does not set the Returns method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, moq

Hello i am using MoQ and i am trying to understand why my method's return value does get used.
In the below example i am creating a service using a mocked interface dependency.I am setting up what the interface method should return.
However when the service uses my mocked dependency the return value is null , not the one i have set in the `Returns` method.
Why does this happen?

**Model**

```
public class SomeModel
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

**Mocked dependency**

```
public interface IDependency
{
    Task<SomeModel> GetByIdAsync(string input);
}
```

**Service using mocked dependency**

```
public class SomeService
{
  private IDependency dependency;
  public SomeService(IDependency dependency)
  {
    this.dependency=dependency;
  }
  public async Task<SomeModel> GetByIdAsync(string id)
  {
     var model=await this.dependency.GetByIdAsync(id); //why is the result null , i have set the `Returns`
     if(model==null)
     {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
     }
     return model;
  }
}
```

**Test class**

```
public class MyTest
{
  [Testcase("data")]
  public async Task CanGetById(string value)
  {
      var model=new SomeModel{Name=value};
      var dependency=new Mock<IDependency>();
      dependency.Setup(x=>x.GetByIdAsync(value)).Returns(Task.FromResult(model)).Verifiable(); //i have set up the return of the dependency
      var service=new SomeService(dependency.Object);
      var clone=await service.GetByIdAsync(value);
      dependency.Verify();
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `data` here `var model=await this.dependency.GetByIdAsync(data);`? Should it be `id`?

Comment: Sorry i forgot it is a typo.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian based on the shown test and the subject under test, this should work provided that the value used in the setup is what was actually passed when invoking the subject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result will only be null if the value passed into the mocked member when invoked does not match what was expected when the mock was Setup

There is also the alternative to using `ReturnsAsync`

For example

```
[Testcase("data")]
public async Task CanGetById(string value) {
    //Arrange
    var model = new SomeModel { Name = value };
    var dependency = new Mock<IDependency>();
    dependency
        .Setup(x => x.GetByIdAsync(value))
        .ReturnsAsync(model)
        .Verifiable(); 

    var service = new SomeService(dependency.Object);

    //Act
    var clone = await service.GetByIdAsync(value);

    //Assert
    dependency.Verify();
}
```

Comment: You are right , i was sending a wrong input to my method.It works fine.Thanks !